# Execute code in one form when another form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have `Form1` and `Form2`.

When I close `Form2` using `this.Close()`, I want `Form1` to detect the close and execute a code.

Can this be done?

Comment: JohnEphraimTugado I would not say it's a duplicate, because Denise probably doesn't know about DialogResult. However, Denise, the link from John is your answer.

Comment: @Antoine Thanks :) I honestly didn't know about the DialogResult and yup :) I'll give it a look

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Thanks for sharing that :) So both the DialogResult and using FormClosing event methods fixed my problem!. I think I'll stick with the DialogResult just because I could do more with it :)

Comment: @Denise just a quick tip. Always hover your mouse over the method just to see what it returns. Most of the times it's not just void. This will help you in the future very often with problems.

Comment: I feel like im being bullied o.o...How can u just say for certain I actually came across those other posts before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can execute whaever you want in `FormClosing` event, but you need to 
 declare a static property on `Form1` and set value on `FormClosing` in `Form2` , write whatever you want to execute in the `set{}` method of peroperty.

```
// in Form 2
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form1.IsForm2Closed = true;
}
```

---

```
// in Form 1
private static _isForm2Closed ;
public static bool IsForm2Closed 
{
    get
    {
        return _isForm2Closed;
    }
    set
    {
        _isForm2Closed = value;

       if(value)
       {
           // do whatever you want to execute here.
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going as far as this, why not just subscribe to the `FormClosing` event of `Form2` from `Form1`? The problem you've got at the moment, is that if you want to alter any instance members or call any instance methods in `Form1`, you can't, because your code is using a static property. It also seems like a misuse of property setters.

Comment: this is a good idea, could you make an example of it, and put it here?

Comment: @SiavashGhanbari So in form1 i'll just constantly execute a code to check that bool `IsForm2Closed`?

Comment: @Denise yes that is what I mean, this will be work, but I think John comment is considerable.

Comment: @SiavashGhanbari Yup :) Actually both methods fixed my issue. thanks for helping me :)

Comment: @Denise What John means here is that you subscribe to the FormClosing event like in this answer but then from `Form1` when you make it (it being `Form2`)